# Bulk insert, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a need to take in a list of ID numbers corresponding to a member.  Their can be anywhere from 10 to 10,000 being processed at any given time.  I have no problem collecting the data, parsing the data and loading it in to a DataTable or anything (C#) but I want to do some operations in the database.  What is the best way to insert all of this data into a table?

I am pretty sure I don't want run a for each statement and insert 10,000 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class before to do a couple million adds. It seemed pretty handy.

Comment: Agreed (+1). This can use either DataTable or IDataReader, and is by far the best way to bulk insert from .NET into SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You may not want to execute an INSERT 10,000 times, but you can wrap those 10,000 inserts into 1 transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can INSERT a SELECT like this:

INSERT INTO myTable (a, b, c) SELECT d, e, f FROM anotherTable WHERE ...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2008 you can pass the C# data set (the actual DataTable object) as a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx). The parameter is available in your Transact-SQL code as an `@table` variable you can query and manipulate.