# gridview to sql server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

is there any way to insert in bulk (i mean all gridview rows) to sql server database in single submit. its an ASP.Net app and I also want to validate data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396018/bulk-insert-with-gridview-using-c-asp-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566022/updating-batches-of-data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296100/bulk-insert-asp-net

Comment: @marc_s I am calling a SP from C# and binding that DataTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at using [SqlBulkCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In oracle we have batch insert for example

your query returns two rows with column name as a,b,c

```
a:b:c
1:2:3
4:5:5
```

you can use

```
insert into tab_name(a,b,c)(qry)
commit;
```

Make it dynamic and it should work.